# Tabs are hiding icons for child pages iOS TabbedRenderer

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am implementing tabs in iOS using Xamarin.Forms `TabbedRenderer`. But tabs are hiding icons after moving to child pages.

Below is my code

```
public class CustomTabRenderer_iOS : TabbedRenderer
{
  public override void ViewWillLayoutSubviews()
   {
      base.ViewWillLayoutSubviews();

      foreach (var item in TabBar.Items)
       {    
         item.Image = GetTabIcon(item.Title);                                   
       }
   }

  private UIImage GetTabIcon(string title)
  {
      UITabBarItem item = null;
      switch (title)
      {
        case "Dairy":
        item = new UITabBarItem("Dairy", UIImage.FromFile("dairy"), 0);
        break;
        case "My kid":
        item = new UITabBarItem("My kid",UIImage.FromFile("kid"),0);
        break;
        case "Events":
        item = new UITabBarItem("Events", UIImage.FromFile("events"), 0);

        break;
        case "About":
        item = new UITabBarItem("About", UIImage.FromFile("about"), 0);
        break;
      }
      var img = (item != null) ? UIImage.FromImage(item.SelectedImage.CGImage, item.SelectedImage.CurrentScale, item.SelectedImage.Orientation) : new UIImage();
      return img;
  }

}
```

This is Attendance.xaml page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Shared:CToolbarPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="edTheSIS.Pages.Attendance"
    Title="My Kid"
    Icon="kid"
    xmlns:Shared="clr-namespace:edTheSIS.Shared;assembly=edTheSIS">
    <ContentPage.Content>
       <StackLayout>
       <Label Text="This is attendance..!"
       </StackLayout>
   </ContentPage.Content>
</Shared:CToolbarPage>
```

Below Attendance Button click event

```
 private async void CreateTabs()
  {
    var tp = new MyTabbedPage();
    tp.Children.Add(new DairyTabPage());
    tp.Children.Add(new Attendance());
    tp.Children.Add(new Events());
    tp.Children.Add(new About());
    tp.CurrentPage = tp.Children[1];
    await Navigation.PushAsync(tp);
  }
```

For more information see below output screenshot where "My Kid" tab icon not showing

[image]

Comment: Try not setting an icon on the child page, remove: `Icon="kid"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the issue I had due to, In child pages I wasn't setting proper *Title* & based on *Title* only icons was setting. In below method

```
 private UIImage GetTabIcon(string title)
  {
    UITabBarItem item = null;
    switch (title)
    {
      case "Dairy":
      item = new UITabBarItem("Dairy", UIImage.FromFile("dairy"), 0);
      break;
      case "My kid":
      item = new UITabBarItem("My kid",UIImage.FromFile("kid"),0);
      break;
     }
      var img = (item != null) ? UIImage.FromImage(item.SelectedImage.CGImage, item.SelectedImage.CurrentScale, item.SelectedImage.Orientation) : new UIImage();
      return img;
  }
```